# $r$-representation of Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dirac-delta-distributions, matrix-elements

I am watching this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYgX5pdncG8

at 14:30, it has

$\langle r|H|r'\rangle = H(r) \delta(r-r') $

Can you help me to understand why it is so? I thought it should be $H(r,r')$. I believe I am missing some fundamental knowledge in quantum mechanics.

Comment: It is simply an expansion in terms of the eigenfunctions of the position space.

Comment: Could you write what's the Hamiltonian supposed to be? I couldn't see that from around minute 14. My point is that that notation is dangerous and could well be plain wrong. Ask yourself what is that 'matrix element' for the kinetic energy term. It is true however that most Hamiltonians are local, in particular are zero outside the diagonal $r=r'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you are correct, the notation
$$H(r, r') = \langle r | \hat H |r' \rangle$$ is good. This indicates it is the matrix element of the Hamiltonian in the position representation and as such depends on both coordinates.

In the case in question (and many physical cases) the Hamiltonian is *diagonal* in position space (potentials are local) and this is indicated by the delta function: $H(r, r') = H(r) \delta(r - r') = H(r') \delta(r - r') $. The first factor contains all the "interesting" physics about the form of the Hamiltonian and the delta function tells us that only the diagonal elements are non zero.